# Use a custom font for our e-mail campaigns

Tags: email, fonts

I know that you "can't" use a custom font for your e-mails in tools like ActiveCampaign, but I'm subscribed to a newsletter that does use Open Sans among other fonts. I have asked them how they did it but I didn't received any answer.
I'm receiving the emails in my gmail address, so I know it is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A very few email clients support `@font-face` in CSS and the use of custom fonts. (See [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/) for details.)

[image: Can I email… @font-face]

There’s one specificity of Gmail (desktop webmail) which does support fonts like `Google Sans` or `Roboto`. But that’s not because it supports `@font-face` for those, but only because Gmail embeds these fonts itself for its own interface, thus making them available within emails as well.